# How to change date format from YYYY/MM/DD to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: r, date

I have a column of dates which were read in as `character` values (yes, they are supposed to be the same):

```
str(df$date)

$ date : chr  "30/08/2017" "30/08/2017" "30/08/2017" "30/08/2017"
```

I then convert the values to `Date` format:

```
str(df$date)

$ date : Date, format: "2017-08-30" "2017-08-30" "2017-08-30"
```

The problem is that no matter which method I choose to use, the resulting dates are always in `YYYY/MM/DD` format, which is not what I want; they should be in `DD/MM/YYYY` format.

I try:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df$date <- strptime(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

and they all produce the same format.

I have read numerous similar Stack Overflow posts as well as some guides and have tried things like getting and setting my system locale (United Kingdom) and all is correct in that respect.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I believe you want `strftime()`, not `strptime()`. R combines the documentation for these functions, so it can be a little confusing.

Comment: @jdobres THAT'S IT!

Comment: Great. I've fleshed out the comment into an answer, for anyone with a similar issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I try:
>
> ```
> df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
> df$date <- strptime(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
> df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
> ```
>
> and they all produce the same format.

R has two very similarly named functions: `strptime`, which converts from character strings to Date data, and `strftime`, which converts Dates to formatted strings. To make matters worse, the documentation for these two functions is combined, so it can be very hard to keep their uses straight. You want `strftime`, in this case.

Comment: I added the quote from op because on first reading I had thought it wasn't really answering the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `format`:

```
date = c("30/08/2017", "30/08/2017", "30/08/2017", "30/08/2017")
date <- as.Date(date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
# > date
# [1] "2017-08-30" "2017-08-30" "2017-08-30" "2017-08-30"

date = format(date, "%m/%d/%Y")
# > date
# [1] "08/30/2017" "08/30/2017" "08/30/2017" "08/30/2017"
```

Turns into `character` class:

```
# > class(date)
# [1] "character"
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
$variable = '2018/09/18';
$date = str_replace('/', '/', $variable);
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($date));
```

Please check and let me know if you need any more help.